# How to get multiple fields from one criteria using SQL group by?

Tags: sql, mysqli

This query could return the wrong name, because the names I want to query are the ones of the smallest animals of each species. How could I get the right `a.name`

```
SELECT 
a.name,
MIN(a.size)

FROM animal a
LEFT JOIN species s ON s.idSpecies = a.idAnimal

GROUP BY s.id
```

Comment: How does animal relate to species? (column wise...)

Comment: try this:

    select 
    a.name,
    min(a.size)
    
    from animal a
    left join species s    
    group by a.name, s.id

Comment: adding a.name to the group by will return more rows instead. How could we just get the name of the smallest animal of each species? @jarlh edit: left join on id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach for this, is to first find the smallest size of animal per species (as you have done), although I am assuming that species can never be null since an animal must belong to a species, it also does not require a join to species at this point:

```
SELECT  a.IDSpecies, MIN(a.Size) AS Size
FROM    Animal AS a
GROUP BY a.IDSpecies
```

Now you can join the result of this query back to your main query to filter the results.

```
SELECT  a.Name AS AnimalName,
        a.Size,
        s.Name AS SpeciesName
FROM    Animal AS a
        INNER JOIN Species AS s
            ON s.ID = a.IDSpecies
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  a.IDSpecies, MIN(a.Size) AS Size
            FROM    Animal AS a
            GROUP BY a.IDSpecies
        ) AS ma
            ON ma.IDSpecies = a.IDSpecies
            AND ma.Size = a.Size;
```

Another way of doing this, is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  a.Name AS AnimalName,
        a.Size,
        s.Name AS SpeciesName
FROM    Animal AS a
        INNER JOIN Species AS s
            ON s.ID = a.IDSpecies
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Animal AS a2
            WHERE   a2.IDSpecies = a.IDSpecies
            AND     a2.Size < a.Size
        );
```

So you start with a simple select, then use `NOT EXISTS` to remove any animals, where a smaller animal exists in the same species.

Since MySQL will [optimize `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` better than `NOT EXISTS`](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), then the better way of writing the query in MySQL is:

```
SELECT  a.Name AS AnimalName,
        a.Size,
        s.Name AS SpeciesName
FROM    Animal AS a
        INNER JOIN Species AS s
            ON s.ID = a.IDSpecies
        LEFT JOIN Animal AS a2
            ON a2.IDSpecies = a.IDSpecies
            AND a2.Size < a.Size
WHERE   a2.ID IS NULL;
```

The concept is *exactly* the same as `NOT EXISTS`, but does not require a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Following the simple example of Group By :

```
SELECT C.CountryName Country, SN.StateName,  COUNT(CN.ID) CityCount 
FROM Table_StatesName SN 
JOIN Table_Countries C ON C.ID = SN.CountryID
JOIN Table_CityName CN ON CN.StateID = SN.ID
GROUP BY C.CountryName,  SN.StateName  ORDER BY SN.StateName
```

OUTPUT :

```
Country         StateName                       CityCount

Australia       Australian Capital Territory    219
Australia       New South Wales                 2250
Australia       Northern Territory              218
Australia       Queensland                      2250
Australia       South Australia                 1501
Australia       Tasmania                        613
Australia       Victoria                        2250
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all rows with size = smallest size. Use a correlated sub-quert to find that smallest size:

```
SELECT *
FROM animal a
  LEFT JOIN species s ON s.idSpecies = a.idAnimal
where a.size = (select min(a2.size)
                from animal a2
                  LEFT JOIN species s2 ON ss.idSpecies = as.idAnimal
                where s.id = s2.id)
```